# R bootstrapping based on some conditions

Tags: r

I'm trying to do bootstrapping on a dataset based on some conditions.

Below is a snapshot of my data, top row being the column names. My data has about 10k rows.

```
v1 
0
0
0
0
1
0
0
0
1
0
0
```

I would like to generate a new dataset by randomly re-sampling v1 until there is a 1 and take the count of observation. For example, the first iteration resample the data x number of times until 1 appears and records the number of times it resample the data.

Adding more details as I had been unclear...

Here is an example output...

```
bootstrap_output
3
10
5
1
6
7
```

The number is a result of how many 'try' of resampling in v1 to attain the value of 1. 
For the first row, it re-sample v1 three times until there is a 1. So the resampling sequence was (0,0,1). The second row's resampling sequence was (0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1)

Comment: Unclear to me what exactly you want to do

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for a geometric distribution where 0 denotes failure and 1 is success and you sample until you pick a 1.

```
set.seed(1L)
DF <- data.frame(v1=c(0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0))
(bootstrap_output <- rgeom(6, sum(DF$v1) / nrow(DF)))
```

sample output with `set.seed(1L)`:

```
#[1]  3  2 13  0  6  1
```